# How to change status on a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to change the status of `Dispute` object:

```
class Dispute < ActiveRecord::Base
  STATUSES = %w(open finished).freeze
  STATUSES.each do |method|
    define_method "#{method}?" do
      status == method
    end
  end

  def self.statuses
    STATUSES
  end
end
```

in `create` and `update` methods:

```
def create
  Dispute.new
  if params[:status] == 'Open'
    dispute.status = dispute.statuses[0]
  end
  if dispute.save
    redirect_to dispute_path(@dispute)
    flash[:success] = 'Hooray'
  else
    flash[:error] = 'Error'
    redirect_to :back
  end
end
```

I handled the attribute inside the method, but the status did not change. Is it better to change the status in the model with callback instead of the controller?

Answer (score 0):

To change the status you can simply do

```
def create
  Dispute.new
  if params[:status] == 'Open'
    dispute.status = dispute.statuses.open!
  end
  if dispute.save
    redirect_to dispute_path(@dispute)
    flash[:success] = 'Hooray'
  else
    flash[:error] = 'Error'
    redirect_to :back
  end
end
```

you can visit http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html for more help on enumns.